# Callback fail in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following section of jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#loginAccount').click(function(){ // Create `click` event function for login
    var login_result = $('#loginAccountCallBack'); // Get the login result div
    login_result.html('<span class="error">Enter the username</span>');
  });
});
```

I would expect my div with id `loginAccountCallBack` to echo the text `"Enter the username"` - please could someone explain why this doesn't happen?

Comment: you are alerting an object. that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Can you show your HTML.

Comment: This is a good first question, you are showing what you are asking and what you have done. I have slightly reformatted to make it clearly a single question. Could you also include the HTML as requested above, as reviewers can then check if the problem actually lies there and not in the jQuery itself.

Answer (score 0):

You're only alerting the jQuery element of `$('#loginAccountCallBack')` -- run a method on that such as `.val()` to retrieve the value (assuming it's of type `input`)

Comment: just a small note, he did say it is a div in the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) if you want to get the inner HTML of a div:

```
var login_result = $('#loginAccountCallBack').html();
```